# How to optimize a spark join function

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have two dataframes and i do make a join between them.

I'm currently looking into adding a function to this join.
i have ids in the first dataframe and them description in the second.

this is my essay:

```
// my small file
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/zed/file/app_desc")
// create an RDD[(String, String)] 
// collectAsMap and broadcast on the result
val id_dec: Broadcast[Map[String, String]] = sc.broadcast(rdd.map(line=>(line.split(";")(0),line.split(";")(1))).collectAsMap)
// create a function : take the id and return the descriptions
def extract_connection_type(input: String): String = {
  if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
    input
  else try {
    id_dec.value(input)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => throw new IOException("UDF:Caught exception processing input row :" + input + e.toString);
  }
}
// apply my function into my schema
def structure(line: String): structure_Ot = {
  val fields = line.split("\\\t",-1)
  val Name1 = fields(0)
  val Name2 = fields(1)
  val Appd = fields(2)
  val App = extract_connection_type(Appd)
  val ot_str = structure_Ot(Name1, Name2, App.toInt)
  ot_str
}
```

I was just wondering how i can optimize my job; it still take alot of time.
(as i mentioned that i'm making a join between a very big table and small one)

I'm open to new ideas.
Thanks,

Comment: where is structure_0t function? is it a case class or a function?

Comment: There's no join in your code

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan its' case class. @T. Gawęda 22 it's a join function of hive table (load it from a csv ) and a big dataframe

Comment: why are you broadcasting description data? I would suggest you to create both data as dataframes and join them with common field. I couldn't give you more information as your question doesn't contain enough information on how you want to join and what is the time consuming part.